# Property returning undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

When I create the prototype out of scope, but referencing it I can not reach the nome property.

```
'use strict';

function Cachorro(nome) {
    this.nome = nome;

    this.late = () => {
        console.log(`${this.nome}: Au au au!`);
    }
};

Cachorro.prototype.morde = () => {
    console.log(`${this.nome}: #mordendo`);
}

const dolly = new Cachorro("Dolly");


dolly.late()
dolly.morde()
```

Comment: That's the point of using an arrow function. Don't use an arrow function.

Comment: Related: [Arrow function vs function declaration / expressions: Are they equivalent / exchangeable?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34361379/218196)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that ES6 arrow functions always inherit `this` of the parent scope. Because of this, you do not want to use them for prototype functions since `this` would be the only way to get at that object instance's properties.

So convert this:

```
Cachorro.prototype.morde = () => {
    console.log(`${this.nome}: #mordendo`);
}
```

to:

```
Cachorro.prototype.morde = function() {
    console.log(`${this.nome}: #mordendo`);
}
```